# Variable width on posts using post count

Tags: wordpress, loops, count

I'm setting up a loop and with help from the `$count` I want to have different classes to the posts.

However, I want the `$count` to be dynamic, now I have to manually state the class depending on if the post count is equal to a number or not, as you can see in the code below.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1
);

$loop = new WP_query( $args );
$count = 0;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$count++;
if( $count == 1) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item','six');
} elseif ( $count == 2) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item','three');
} elseif ( $count == 3) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item','three');
} elseif ( $count == 4) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item', 'six');
} elseif ( $count == 5) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item', 'six');
} elseif ( $count == 6) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item', 'three');
} else {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item', 'three');
}
    ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

The number six and three are the classes of the posts.

What I want to execute.

Post 1 = class 6 
Post 2 = class 3 
Post 3 = class 3 
Post 4 = class 6 
Post 5 = class 6 
Post 6 = class 3 
Post 7 = class 3 
Post 8 = class 6 
Post 9 = class 6

And so forth.

Maybe, I'm looking at it the wrong way, the `$count` might not even be the way to go.

Appreciate all help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, without comparing each count individually.

```
if( $count == 1 || $count == 4 || $count == 5) {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item','six');
} else {
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item', 'three');
}
```

Or you can even try like this

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1
);

$loop = new WP_query( $args );
$count = 0;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$count++;
    get_template_part( 'parts/case/item', 'somecontentpart');
?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

then in template part's class add following code

```
class="<?php echo ( $count == 1 || $count == 4 || $count == 5) ? 'class6' : 'class3';?>"
```